# Incrementing and decremening a single shared variable with multiple Threads

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, bluej

When incrementing and decrementing multiple threads using a single shared variable, how can I ensure that the threads count in a syncronized way and don't skip any value.

I have created a seperate class in which I have 3 different methods, one to increment, another to decrement and the last one to return the value. they are all synchronized as well.

The result shows an example:

- This is Thread_4 iteration: -108 of 500
  This is Thread_5 iteration: 291 of 500
  This is Thread_4 iteration: -109 of 500
  This is Thread_4 iteration: -110 of 500

As you can see the threads are decrementing but then it jumps to "291" which should not happen as I am using a shared variable.

******************************EDIT*****************

CODE:- SHARED VARIABLE CLASS

```
public class shareVar extends Thread
{
    private static int sharedVariable = 0;


    public synchronized static void increment(){
        sharedVariable++;
    }

    public synchronized static void decrement(){
        sharedVariable--;
    }

    public  static int value(){
        return sharedVariable;
    }
}
```

----- Incrementing Class

```
sVar incrementVal = new sVar();

public synchronized void display(){

    for(int countVal = 0; countVal<=max; countVal++ ){
            incrementVal.increment();
            System.out.println("This is " + threadName + " iteration: " + incrementVal.value() + " of " + max);
            //this.yield();
    }
    System.out.println("*THIS " + threadName + " IS FINISH " 
                                    + "INCREMENTING *");

}

public void run(){

    display();
}
```

Comment: Can't tell without code posted

Comment: put your code to let us understand ur problem better.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Answer (score 6):

Consider using [`AtomicInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html):

```
public class Foo
{
    private AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);

    public void increment()
    {
        counter.incrementAndGet();
    }

    public void decrement()
    {
        counter.decrementAndGet();
    }

    public int getValue()
    {
        return counter.get();
    }
}
```

---

or using the synchronized methods:

```
public class Foo
{
    private volatile int counter;

    public synchronized void increment()
    {
        counter++;
    }

    public synchronized void decrement()
    {
        counter--;
    }

    public int getValue()
    {
        return counter;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have done this already and I am still not getting a completely synchronized incrementing and decrementing count.                                                   *****(This is Thread_2 iteration: -9 of 500
This is Thread_2 iteration: -8 of 500
This is Thread_1 iteration: -135 of 500
This is Thread_1 iteration: -7 of 500
This is Thread_1 iteration: -6 of 500)

Comment: Is it possible to run both increment and decerement in one method instead of having two different method?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your question correctly, but your output looks the way it is just because another thread (Thread_4) gets to work on the value before Thread_5 outputs it.

There are a number of operations going on in each iteration (simplified list, in reality there are more than these):

1. Increment/decrement
2. Get the current value
3. Create the output String
4. Output the output String

And another thread may get a turn between any of these operations. So it could be that Thread_5 does what it does, then other threads get turns and only after a while Thread_5 outputs the result.

If you want the new values to be output in order, you need to output the current value inside the synchronized block, ie. the increment/decrement methods.

Comment: I think I understand what your saying, would it be possible to see an example?

Comment: Is it possible to run both increment and decrement in one method instead of having two different methods?

Comment: Just put the System.out.println inside of the increment() or decrement(). If you want to use one method for both operations, use a method parameter to indicate which operation it is. Like operate(boolean increment).

Comment: Thanks.. I tried but I still get a few sections where within the threads that still is not following the order where 1 or 2 thread might have random values.

Comment: Did you use just one method or still two? I just realized that you _must_ use just one to achieve the ordering. That should help.